# Remove row names for a list of data frames using map

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list containing two data frames, each with row names that I would like to remove:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- list(tbl1 = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:3], row.names = 1:3),
            tbl2 = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:3], row.names = 1:3))
```

I know that I can accomplish this using the following function:

```
rownum_fun <- function(x) {
  rownames(dat[[x]]) <<- NULL
}

names(dat) %>% 
  map(~rownum_fun(.x))
```

What I was wondering was whether there was any way to do this without storing the rowname removal process as a function, and instead having it live inside the map statement? Something along the lines of what is shown below, which currently does not work:

```
names(dat) %>% 
  map(~rownames(dat[[.x]]) <<- NULL)
```

Alternatively, if there is a completely different and better way to do this would be open to that as well. Mostly just looking for a more efficient solution, if one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are already in the tidyverse, one possibility is to use `tibble::remove_rownames()` like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

dat <- list(tbl1 = data.frame(x = runif(3), row.names = LETTERS[1:3]),
            tbl2 = data.frame(x = runif(3), row.names = LETTERS[1:3]))
dat

# $tbl1
#           x
# A 0.9148060
# B 0.9370754
# C 0.2861395
# 
# $tbl2
#           x
# A 0.8304476
# B 0.6417455
# C 0.5190959

dat %>% 
  map(~ remove_rownames(.)) -> dat
dat

# $tbl1
#           x
# 1 0.9148060
# 2 0.9370754
# 3 0.2861395
# 
# $tbl2
#           x
# 1 0.8304476
# 2 0.6417455
# 3 0.5190959
```

Comment: The base equivalent is `dat %>% map(\`rownames<-\`, NULL)` (by base I mean a base function embedded in a tidyverse pipe and mapped with `purrr:map`)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`tibble::remove_rownames()`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html)

NB : Your row.names still display because by default R console numbers the rows, so I gave them letters instead.

```
library(tidyverse)

(dat <- list(tbl1 = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:3], 
                               row.names = LETTERS[1:3]),
             tbl2 = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:3],
                               row.names = LETTERS[1:3])))
```

```
$tbl1
  x
A A
B B
C C

$tbl2
  x
A A
B B
C C
```

```
dat %>% 
  map(~ remove_rownames(.))
```

```
$tbl1
  x
1 A
2 B
3 C

$tbl2
  x
1 A
2 B
3 C
```